# Python : Animate changing color of nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

How Can I Change The Color Of Any Nodes In python Using Networkx And Animation in networkx Dynamically

I Want That The Nodes Color Change Dynamically After Some Time Interval

Can I Do This In Networkx , with Animation in Language Python

Comment: Please post examples of what you have tried so far, and any errors that occurred when you tried them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends in how you want to accomplish this for instance the below code will allow me to change the color:

```
    import networkx as nx
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(30,0.5)
    colors = ['r','g','b','y','m']
    x = 1
    while x != 0:
        x = eval(input("Input a number (0 to quit): "))
        rand = np.random.randint(0,6)
        nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color = colrs[rand])
        plt.show()
        time.sleep(5)
```

This accomplishes what you are asking but you may want something different which I can't tell from what you asked.